# How to set this conditional formatting with multiple criteria using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I've been trying to get this one to work and it even did a couple of times, but not quite right as needed. Now, when I check the rules applied, it's blank, although it gives me no error. I'm guessing the error is in the formula/conditions...

```
    Dim Lr As Long
    Lr = MyResults.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'MyResult is declared above and it's right. 
    With MyResults.Range("A12:H" & Lr)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E($A12<>"",$F12=0)")
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 232, 234)
        End With
    End With
```

The highlighted line should be light red.

Appreciate your time.

[image]

Comment: I am not entirely sure anymore, but I seem to recall that formula expressions written from VBA are not regional - Try replacing the ```=E(...``` with ```=AND(...``` by any chance?

Comment: This is ended up being the correct way: ````=E($A12>0;$F12=0)```` . and 'E', because my Excel is in Portuguese. Thank you, @FranzReischl

Comment: I switched my Excel to English precisely because of such pitfalls. Glad you got it working.